# In Python, return specific item in list of Tuples, using bisect

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a program to quickly find the wire size quickly so I don't have to reference a chart all the time but am having a small issue.

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
#From Table 310.16 - Article 310 - 
#75 degree rated Copper RHW,THHW,THWN,XHHW,USE,ZW - 2008 NEC
wireAmpacityTable = [
    (25, '#12'),
    (35, '#10'),
    (50, '#8'),
    (65, '#6'),
    (85, '#4'),
    (100, '#3'),
    (115, '#2'),
    (130, '#1'),
    (150, '1/0'),
    (175, '2/0'),
    (200, '3/0'),
    (230, '4/0'),
    (255, '250MCM'),
    (285, '300MCM'),
    (310, '350MCM'),
    (335, '400MCM'),
    (380, '500MCM'),
    (420, '600MCM'),
]
```

I was successfully able to use the bisect function to get me the right wire size.

My question is how can I access just the wire size value. For example if I input 15 amps I want it to return just the wire size - #12. Currently it returns `(25, '#12')`

Here is the code I wrote to lookup the values

```
import bisect
# sort list 
wireAmpacityTable.sort()

def wireLookup(amps):
    pos1 = bisect.bisect_right(wireAmpacityTable, (amps,))
    print "ampacity"
    print wireAmpacityTable[pos1]

amp = int(raw_input("How many Amps:"))
print wireLookup(amp)
```

Comment: That's a list of tuples, not a list of dicts

Comment: fixed the title. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment `wireLookup` returns nothing. First you have to return something (and not just print it) and second you just need the second entry of the tuple.

```
return wireAmpacityTable[pos1][1]
```

By the way, you might want to name your functions and variables according to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you! I am also going to read through PEP-8 and reworking my functions and variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just index into the tuple, the gauge of wire is at position 1 so

```
print wireAmpicity[posl][1]
```

Will print out just the wire gauge.